# REACT HOOKS - Passing JSON data (From API through Axios) into const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, mapping

In the backend I am processing the data and then sending it to React through JSON. Here is the code.

```
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  var obj = {field: current, fieldCnt: cnt }
  var obj2 = JSON.stringify(obj)
  res.write(obj2);
  var obj3 = {length: currentcnt, field2: current, fieldCnt2: cnt }
  var obj4 = JSON.stringify(obj3)
  res.end(obj4);
```

The backend I showed here is not the same as it is. I just showed it as an example. I had to use res.write and res.end because I had to collect data for different if conditions.

Below here is the code in react where I am getting this data through Axios.

```
var data2 =  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get').then(res => {
   console.log(res.data)      //Check the Attached Chrome Developers console image.
   return res.data
});

const data3 = data2.length   //This isn't working (length can be seen the console image last line "length" : 18)
```

[Chrome Developers console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrVpR.png)

Please tell me how to solve this with React Hooks. I think it has to be done with mapping but i don't how.

Comment: Can you share what is the error coming, also is the data returned a nested object?

Comment: `axios.get(...)` returns a Promise. You are assigning `data3` the length of the promise, not the length of the response.

Comment: There is no error coming, but the value of data3 comes to be 0.

Comment: ts giving me the length of something else. I want the length from the JSON data I received from the API. See the Image attached in the question. In the last line there is "length": 18 I want to get this value of length –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tobias Geiselmann said `axios.get()` returns a promise, and you're assigning the length of the promise.

If you return a value from `.then()`, the next then() is called with that value.

After looking at your screenshot. It looks like you're trying to access the length property from the data return by your API. I would recommend structuring your API response like so

```
{
  count: 18,
  results: [
    { key: 'val' },
    { key: 'val' },
    { key: 'val' },
  ]
}
```

By doing so you'll be to access the length with:

```
res.data.count // will have the count
res.data.results // will have all the results
```

Try this

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get').then((res) => {
   console.log(res.data.length); // will print the length
});
```

another example:

```
const data2 = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get')
  .then((data) => {
    return data;
  });

data2.then(data => {
  console.log(data.length) // will print the length
})
```

example with `async/await`

```
const myFunc = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get');

  console.log(data.length); // will print the length
};
```

Comment: Its giving me the length of something else. I want the length from the JSON data I received from the API. See the Image attached in the question. In the last line there is "length": 18 I want to get this value of length

Answer (score 0):

To solve this with hooks you can fetch data when the component loads with useEffect hook and store it inside useState hook.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get').then(res => setData(res.data))
  }, [])

  const data3 = data.length
```